# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable, BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm running into a strange error. I'm trying to do some basic parsing. Essentially, I'm gathering data in 'x' format, and want to return everything in a format that I can use. My immediate issue is that my code is returning a strange error. I have looked through some of the other posts / answers on here for the same issue, but out of context... it is truly hard to pinpoint the issue.

```
data = url.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html5lib")

results = [] # this is what my result set will end up as

def parseDiv(text):
    #function takes one input parameter - a single div for which it will parse for specific items, and return it all as a dictionary
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(text)
    title = soup2.find("a", "yschttl spt")
    print title.text
    print

    return title.text

for result in soup.find_all("div", "res"):
    """
    This is where the data is first handled - this would return a div with links, text, etc -
    So, I pass the blurb of text into the parseDiv() function
    """
    item = parseDiv(result)
    results.append(item)
```

Obviously at this point, I've included my needed libraries... When I pull the code for soup2 (the second instantiation of bs4 on my new blurbs of text to be processed), and just print the input of my function, it all works.

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testdata.py", line 29, in <module>
    item = parseDiv(result)
  File "testdata.py", line 17, in parseDiv
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(text)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\__i
    markup = markup.read()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: Please post the complete error stack trace.

Comment: "but out of context... it is truly hard to pinpoint the issue" - the same applies to incomplete traceback. can you include all the lines?

Comment: edits made to show stack trace.

Comment: Do you need to run BeautifulSoup on 'text' inside parseDiv?

Comment: @JayanthKoushik I was thinking it was the best way to go through the text once it was inside of the function.. as each div that gets passed in has several child elements, attributes, etc... and as a beginner, it seemed like the easiest thing to do. Obviously I've been wrong thus far

Comment: This question is fairly old - yet, I had exactly the same issue. The solution was to realize what python thought the type passed as parameter was. `print(type(text))`, which revealed `bs4.element.Tag` as type, not str.   So you can just do `text.findAll` etc directly from parameter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to parse the divs once again. Try this:

```
for div in soup.find_all('div', 'res'):
    a = div.find('a', 'yschttl spt')
    if a:
        print a.text
        print
        results.append(a)
```

Comment: Thanks @Jayanth, This alleviates one issue, but now I am receiving an attribute error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testdata.py", line 24, in <module>
    item['title'] = a.text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: @Alpinestar22 Then obviously something has returned `None`, and you should check that.

Comment: @Alpinestar22: That would happen if one of the 'divs' does not have an 'a' of class 'yschttl spt'.

Comment: Boom, thank you. When I was first getting the raw data, I guess I just decided that since I wasn't getting errors, that I was getting everything correctly.