# RoboBrowser TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, web-scraping, robobrowser

So I'm using [robobrowser](https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser) which uses bs4. When I try and strip the tags from the strings, I get the error described below. If I comment out `i.strip("</b>")` then I can easily print the list of strings with the tags on the ends. Possible dupe: [TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable, BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21696264/typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-callable-beautifulsoup)

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser as r


browser = r(history=False)
browser.open('http://mp3skull.com/')
usrsearch = "a-ha" #input('Search for music: ')

searchform = browser.get_form(action="/search_db.php")
searchform['q'].value = usrsearch
browser.submit_form(searchform)

songs = browser.select('b')
for i in songs:
    print(i.strip("</b>"))
```

Error:

```
line 13, in <module>
i.strip("</b>")
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: I'm not getting any responses, or any views for that matter. Those 14 views are my own. Bump?

Answer (score 0):

You can use encode_contents() to get the tag contents as a bytestring, without the tag itself.

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser as r

browser = r(history=False)
browser.open('http://mp3skull.com/')
usrsearch = "a-ha" #input('Search for music: ')

searchform = browser.get_form(action="/search_db.php")
searchform['q'].value = usrsearch
browser.submit_form(searchform)

songs = browser.select('b')
for i in songs:
    print(i.encode_contents())
```

I couldn't find information on all the BeautifulSoup4 tag properties and methods in the [official documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). However, I did find [this page](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/docs/ios/beautifulsoup_ref.html) which lists more information on the properties and methods.